# Where is this file located?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am modifying some code that I did not write and trying to figure out why the login is not working. It's an ajax call to the file below. However, this path does not exist on the server. This exact script works on a different server and the files all match up between the two. Has anyone seen this type of set up before?

Here is the ajax call and my console output when I click the login button...

```
$.ajax({
   url : "<?php echo base_url()?>welcome/set_session",
   data: {username: userID, password: passHash},
   type: "POST",
   success: function(safe) {
```

Here is the console output...
     POST http://www.resuscitationalliance.com/tool/welcome/set_session 404 (Not Found)

Comment: eww.. using php inside js :o and not seen anything like that, servers, both production and testing should match (save anything in gitignore.. if you use git)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I don't understand your comment? What's wrong with the server side php-clause inside that javascript? You do know that the php is executed on the server side and the javascript the browser sees is different than the one in the question?

Comment: yes... very much do I know that haha but it's terrible practice to use php inside JS.. don't mix languages :p

Comment: I mix languages all the time. Not sure what the problem is. In this file, the JS is written at the bottom of a PHP page. Not the most uncommon way to write.

I have figured this issue out. The path is pointing to a method inside a class. I've never seen it written that way before and I'm not sure how it works, but I can figure it out from here. Thanks.

Comment: @stevenpepe there isn't too much wrong with doing it, other than it looks messy and what handles what. E.g. your server will pass the variable to the browser to handle, whereas, if it was pure js it would just be handled by the browser, and vice versa.. and ahh I see, I'm guessing a bespoke MVC?